# Display/list database tables and relationships in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to visually represent the tables in a sql database; showing relationships, if there are any, between the different tables? Thank you.

Comment: Play little with SQL management studio, I am sure you will find out the solution :)

Comment: I have been using my white board :D...feel like an idiot now because the answer has been staring at me all this time. Anyway, thank you guys...much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL server, under the database name is a folder named "Database Diagrams". Right click and "add new database diagram".

Click on the tables you wish to include, then hit the "Add" button.

Provided you have already setup your relationships the connections will be shown, 1 to many, many to many, etc. You can name and save, then if you add relationships after the fact, they will automatically appear (but if you add tables after the fact, you will have to manually add them to your saved diagram(s)).

You can move the tables and relationship chains around to make it more clear, and add labels for headers, etc. If you have a lot of tables I find zooming out while working on arranging things in a logical order easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Use database diagrams. Here is a link that may help: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/